# Hiding and displaying again a TreeView modifies which TreeViewItem is selected. Why?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, treeview

I have a TreeView in SL4 which is already populated, and with a certain TreeViewItem selected.

Just doing

```
treeview.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
```

and then

```
treeview.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
```

modifies which TreeViewItem is selected. Why? Is there a way to avoid that?

**EDIT 2012.02.04 03:29**

I've traced the problem down to its root. This is the (for me, astonishing) conclusion of what I've found: if all of the following conditions are met:

1) the TreeView has two levels (or more) of depth,

2) I start by I expanding all of its nodes,

3) I start selecting a node at the second level, and

4) (this is the weirdest one) **the button I use to collapse and show again the TreeView is NOT a tab stop**,

then the TreeView does NOT keep its selection after being collapsed and shown again!!!

Please download the small solution+sample that reproduces the problem from
http://src041.bluemosfet.net/treeviewselectsanotheritem.zip
and try it.

or look at these two pieces of code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PRJ.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <StackPanel Name="sp1">
            <!-- ################################################################### -->
            <!-- First, in the TreeView, expand TreeViewItems "a0", "a1" and "a2". -->
            <!-- Then, select "a0b0". -->
            <!-- Then, click the button twice. -->
            <!-- If you don't remove   IsTabStop="False"   from the following line of code, the TreeView reappears with "a1" selected !!! -->
            <!-- If you continue clicking the button, the selection shifts to "a1b0", "a2", and finally "a2b0". -->
            <!-- If you remove   IsTabStop="False"  , or change it to True, the TreeView works OK and keeps its selection. -->
            <!-- Isn't it odd, that the capability of the TreeView to keep its selection depends on whether the button used to hide and show the TreeView is a tab stop or not??? -->
            <Button Content="Hide/Show TreeView" Name="b1" Click="b1_Click" IsTabStop="False" />
            <!-- ################################################################### -->
            <sdk:TreeView Name="tv1" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and

```
namespace PRJ
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void b1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tv1.Visibility==Visibility.Collapsed)
                tv1.Visibility=Visibility.Visible;
            else
                tv1.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int a=0;a<3;a++)
            {
                TreeViewItem    tvia    =new TreeViewItem();
                tvia.Header                =String.Format("a{0}",a);
                for (int b=0;b<2;b++)
                {
                    TreeViewItem    tvib    =new TreeViewItem();
                    tvib.Header                =String.Format("a{0}b{1}",a,b);
                    tvia.Items.Add(tvib);
                } // for b
                tv1.Items.Add(tvia);
            } // for a
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't it odd that the capability of the TreeView to keep its selection or not depends on whether the button used to hide and show the TreeView is a tab stop or not??

Answer (score 0):

did a test with a brand new project and a treeview fed with a list of strings. Never lost the selected item after collapsing and making visible again.

Comment: This is odd. Are you using SL4? I am. I'll post a link to a zip file containing my example solution+project. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, going down (removing things from what I have -a relatively large project-), I don't know what to remove, to eliminate the problem, whereas if I start a brand new project, I don't know what to add, to make the problem appear. So you are right that, with a fresh project, this does not happen. I have to find out what, in my project, is causing this to happen. What I have no doubt about is that, with my setup, and just changing the visibility as I said, the selection goes to another TreeViewItem. I'll continue trying. Thanks.

Comment: Please see my 2012.02.04 03:29 edit with astonishing conclusions.

Comment: Well.. I can now confirm what you see. While the button is not a tab stop (as stated by the IsTabStop="False" you have in XAML), the SelectedItem changes till it raises the bottom of the tree. Really strange indeed. If you set IsTabStop="True", or remove it, this no longer happen and the selection is preserved. Could this help you enough?

Comment: Well, that's what I found (and it doesn't go to the bottom of the tree. The rule is more complex). The problem is that, due to visual appearance, I didn't want the button to be a tab stop (because it draws an extra border when it is, and it has focus). I ended up circumventing the problem in another way (storing the selection just before I would hide the tree -changing to another page-, and later on recreating it). Thank you for your time.